# HIGHCHARTS auto-rotate x-axis labels for custom positioned labels

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart in highcharts with custom shifted x-axis labels (to fit between ticks instead of on ticks) with the last label removed (See this topic for original chart's development: [HIGHCHARTS: Event on Export can't access x-axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656388/highcharts-event-on-export-cant-access-x-axis-labels)). ​

The default auto-rotation does not seem to work when the number of x-axis labels gets large and/or the chart width gets too narrow. Instead the labels are truncated with ellipses ('...'). See image and JS Fiddle below:

[image: Truncated x-axis labels]

JS Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/SirMunchington/g5t4kr7L/2

Here is the code in the jsfiddle since code is required in topics including fiddle links:

Html:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<a href title="Download Chart" id="download-link">Download Chart</a>

<div id="container"></div>
```

JS:

```
var download_link = document.getElementById('download-link');
download_link.onclick = downloadChartImage;

function downloadChartImage() {
  Highcharts.charts[0].exportChartLocal({
    filename: 'test123',
    type: 'image/png',
  })
  return false;
}

chart_options = {
  "colors": ["#f28f43", "#ffea00", "#2f7ed8", "#9370db", "#1aadce", "#8bbc21", "#c42525"],
  "exporting": {
    "chartOptions": {
      "chart": {
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
      }
    },
    "sourceWidth": 1250,
    "sourceHeight": 500,
    "scale": 2,
    "fallbackToExportServer": false,
    "buttons": {
      "contextButton": {
        "enabled": false
      }
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "EDITZ TEST GOAL FOR INSTITUTION Updated Name",
    "style": {
      "color": "#274b6d",
      "fontSize": "16px"
    }
  },
  "chart": {
    "reflow": true,
    "backgroundColor": "transparent",
    "borderRadius": 5,
    "events": {
      render() {
        let chart = this,
          xAxis = chart.xAxis[0],
          ticks = xAxis.ticks,
          firstTick = ticks[xAxis.tickPositions[0]],
          secondTick = ticks[xAxis.tickPositions[1]],
          ticksDistance = secondTick.mark.getBBox().x - firstTick.mark.getBBox().x;

        for (let i in ticks) {
          let tick = ticks[i];
          if (!tick.isLast) {
            tick.label.translate(ticksDistance / 2, 0)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "label": {
        "connectorAllowed": true
      },
      "pointStart": 2011,
      "animation": false,
      "enableMouseTracking": true,
      "stickyTracking": false,
      "shadow": false
    },
    "line": {
      "animation": false,
      "enableMouseTracking": true,
      "shadow": false,
      "marker": {
        "enabled": true
      }
    }
  },
  "legend": {
    "borderColor": "#000000",
    "borderRadius": 5,
    "borderWidth": 1,
    "useHTML": true,
    "adjustChartSize": true,
    "itemHiddenStyle": {
      "color": "#8e8e8e"
    },
    "itemStyle": {
      "fontWeight": "normal",
      "color": "#274b6d"
    },
    "itemDistance": 10,
    "symbolRadius": 2
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "xAxis": {
    "type": "datetime",
    "labels": {
      formatter: function() {
        return moment(this.value).year()
      }
    },
    "tickPositions": [1277967600000, 1309503600000, 1341126000000, 1372662000000, 1404198000000, 1435734000000, 1467356400000, 1498892400000, 1530428400000, 1561964400000, 1593586800000, 1625122800000, 1656658800000, 1688194800000, 1719817200000, 1751439600000, 1783062000000, 1814684400000, 1846306800000, 1877929200000, 1909551600000, 1941174000000, 1972796400000],
    "endOnTick": true,
    "startOnTick": true,
    showLastLabel: false,
    "maxPadding": 0,
    "minPadding": 0,
    "tickLength": 5,
    "title": {
      "text": "Fiscal Year",
      "style": {
        "color": "#4d759e",
        "fontWeight": "bold"
      }
    },
    "plotLines": [{
      "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)",
      "width": 1,
      "value": 1341125999999,
      "dashStyle": "longdash"
    }, {
      "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)",
      "width": 1,
      "value": 1605130646775,
      "dashStyle": "longdash"
    }, {
      "color": "rgba(139, 188, 33, 0.5)",
      "width": 1,
      "value": 1657609200000,
      "dashStyle": "longdash"
    }, {
      "color": "#f28f43",
      "width": 1,
      "value": 1612166400000,
      "dashStyle": "longdash"
    }]
  },
  "yAxis": {
    "tickLength": 5,
    "title": {
      "text": "Energy consumed (MMBtu)",
      "style": {
        "color": "#4d759e",
        "fontWeight": "bold"
      }
    }
  },
  "series": [{
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Past consumption (Projected)",
    "color": "#000000",
    "marker": {
      "symbol": "circle"
    },
    "dashStyle": "Dash",
    "legendIndex": 0,
    "tooltip": {
      "valueDecimals": 0,
      "outside": true,
      "useHTML": true,
      "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
    },
    "data": [
      [1277967599999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1341125999999, 420113.1142557926]
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Consumption (Actual)",
    "color": "#000000",
    "lineWidth": 2,
    "marker": {
      "symbol": "circle"
    },
    "legendIndex": 1,
    "tooltip": {
      "valueDecimals": 0,
      "outside": true,
      "useHTML": true,
      "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
    },
    "data": [
      [1341125999999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1435733999999, -50],
      [1467356399999, 37.53355796084987],
      [1498892399999, 500],
      [1530428399999, -500],
      [1561964399999, 250],
      [1593586799999, -250]
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "scatter",
    "name": "Baseline",
    "color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)",
    "marker": {
      "symbol": "square",
      "radius": 5
    },
    "legendIndex": 2,
    "tooltip": {
      "enabled": true,
      "useHTML": true,
      "outside": true,
      "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
    },
    "data": [
      [1341125999999, 420113.1142557926]
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "line",
    "name": "Baseline consumption",
    "color": "rgba(140, 21, 21, 0.75)",
    "marker": {
      "symbol": "triangle"
    },
    "dashStyle": "Dash",
    "legendIndex": 3,
    "tooltip": {
      "valueDecimals": 0,
      "outside": true,
      "useHTML": true,
      "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
    },
    "data": [
      [1341125999999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1372661999999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1404197999999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1435733999999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1467356399999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1498892399999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1530428399999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1561964399999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1593586799999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1625122799999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1656658799999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1688194799999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1719817199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1751353199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1782889199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1814425199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1845961199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1877497199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1909033199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1940569199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [1972105199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [2003641199999, 420113.1142557926],
      [2035177199999, 420113.1142557926]
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "scatter",
    "name": "Current Date",
    "color": "#000000",
    "marker": {
      "symbol": "circle",
      "radius": 5
    },
    "legendIndex": 4,
    "tooltip": {
      "enabled": true,
      "useHTML": true,
      "outside": true,
      "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
    },
    "data": [
      [1605130646777, 420113.1142557926]
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "scatter",
    "name": "Intermediate Target #1",
    "color": "#f28f43",
    "marker": {
      "symbol": "diamond",
      "radius": 5
    },
    "legendIndex": 5,
    "tooltip": {
      "enabled": true,
      "useHTML": true,
      "outside": true,
      "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
    },
    "data": [
      [1612166400000, 1234]
    ]
  }, {
    "type": "scatter",
    "name": "Primary Target",
    "color": "#8bbc21",
    "marker": {
      "symbol": "diamond",
      "radius": 5
    },
    "legendIndex": 6,
    "tooltip": {
      "enabled": true,
      "valueDecimals": 0,
      "useHTML": true,
      "headerFormat": "<span style=\"font-weight:bold; color:{series.color};\">{series.name}</span><br />"
    },
    "data": [
      [1657609200000, 123]
    ]
  }]
}

Highcharts.chart('container', chart_options)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your problem is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266403/highcharts-xaxis-labels-do-not-auto-rotate) but as of LinusR's answer, autoRotation only works on category charts.
So you can try adding events like load and redraw to call a function to adjust the label rotation based on morganfree's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Inside events load, you can update your xaxis labels rotation and set with the relation of the length of categories, ticks.

```
events: {
  load: function() {
    var chart = this,
      xAxis = chart.xAxis[0];
    console.log(xAxis.categories);

    xAxis.update({
      labels: {
        rotation: 45
      }
    })

  }
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lchtve8a/

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load

---

You can use **xAxis.labels.rotation** to change the auto-rotation labels and adjust the rotation to the responsive design rules **responsive.rules.chartOptions**.
But I'm not sure if you don't mean behavior at export, please specify if so.

```
responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
            maxWidth: 500
        },
        chartOptions: {
            xAxis: {
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value.charAt(0);
                    },
                    rotation: 90
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                labels: {
                    align: 'left',
                    x: 0,
                    y: -2
                },
                title: {
                    text: ''
                }
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Live demo:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/gqysmkat/

API References:

https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules.chartOptions
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.rotation

Comment: Ideally it would be for the web version, first (unless exporting is the same solution). The challenge is that the charts have different number of ticks depending on user, so there is no one rule for what chart width should trigger the rotation. I take it that autorotation does not work for this kind of chart (per your answer and the user's comment on the question above)? Is there no setting for highcharts to auto detect when the labels are overflowing and rotate them in this type of chart?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/Lchtve8a/

Comment: resizing the frame in the fiddle above does not seem to change the labels. Do you have an example on a line chart? Perhaps in a duplicate of my fiddle?

Comment: you have access to the categories, you can now write a function that changes the position of the labels depending on the number of ticks.

Comment: The best way is to use the number of ticks and calculate on this basis. You can probably write a function that counts at what length of a single tick the label should change, but this requires more work and customization.